# Missing Android NDK toolchains directory '\toolchains' when building Xamarin.Android with hosted tfs build server

Tags: tfs, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am trying to set up a `TFS Build agent` to build my `Xamarin.Android` project automatically on every check in.

I have followed the steps outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/apps/xamarin for setting up a Hosted build agent.

TFS Build templates also have a `Xamarin.Android`  template, which you would expect means they are ready to go. This is also backed up from the above link which states you can build a `Xamarin.Android` solution on a Hosted pool

But I keep getting the following error on building the project:

> Missing Android NDK toolchains directory '\toolchains'. Please install
>   the Android NDK

I found a link at Xamarin https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/tfs-and-xa/ which says I need to log onto the build machine and copy and paste the Android NDK onto my remote machine.

But obviously with a hosted pool I cannot log onto machine.

Am I missing something in my setup?

Comment: As extra info if I change this to `debug` instead of `Release` build it works

Comment: Also to note, I can do a `Release` build with the same source on my local machine

Comment: Can you share the entire logs for the failed build?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I have uploaded the `Xamarin.Android` build logs [here](http://www.filedropper.com/5buildxamarinandroidprojectfieldstrikefieldstrikemovefieldstrikemovedroidfieldstrikemovedroidcsproj). I am going to test out the onsite build agent, just setting it up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by Step guide to solving this issue.

If you can I would advise setting up your own build Host using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with Xamarin and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows). After doing so you can use [this Xamarin link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/tfs-and-xa/) to make sure. 1. your java SDK and NDK are in a local (non user specific area, which if you installed using visual studio they should be) and the Enviroment variables have been added (from the Xamarin link):

> Adjusting Environment Variables During the automated build process
>   Xamarin.Android will require access to the Android SDK and NDK at the
>   paths that were adjusted above. This is best done by setting ot
>   adjusting several server wide environment variables:
>
> If not already, log in to the TFS machine as Administrator. Open
>   Control Panel, type Environment in the search box, select Edit the
>   system environment variables, and then click the Environment
>   Variables... button to bring up the following dialog:
>
> Under System variables select ANDROID_HOME and click Edit…, or if
>   ANDROID_HOME doesn’t exist, click New… to create it:
>
> Set the value to c:\android-sdk (or wherever you moved the SDK) and
>   click OK. Under System variables select ANDROID_NDK_PATH and click
>   Edit… (or New… if necessary):
>
> Set the value to c:\android-ndk\android-ndk-r8d (or wherever you moved
>   the NDK) and click OK. Note that you do need the second folder name in
>   this value. Select the Path variable, click Edit… button, and append
>   ;c:\android-sdk (or whatever folder you used) to the end of the path
>   and click OK. Don’t forget to include the semi-colon (;) separator
>   between this and previous entries.
>
> Verify the changes by opening a command prompt, entering Set, and
>   examining the variables. The Team Foundation Server should now be able
>   to build Android apps in a team project.

after this you must set the following properties to `False` in your project.Android.csproj file.

open the file in notepad,
go to the Release configuration section
and set the following to false:

```
<AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
<BundleAssemblies>False</BundleAssemblies>
```

Your project will now build on a hosted pool!

Although I think this hides the real issue as setting these to true will build on your local build agent.

I think the microsoft hosted pool is missing the Android NDK enviroment variable as it doesnt show up in the capabilities in TFS

Answer (score 10):

The original problem was about building a Xamarin Android App on an Azure DevOps hosted agent and having an error because the Android NDK can't be found.

Yes, the build will work if you disable options like `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk` or `BundleAssemblies`, but this is not a true solution, especially when you need those options to be enabled.

As the Android NDK path is not found when building on a hosted agent, the solution is to manually set the Android NDK path.
In the build task, in the MSBuild Options, provide the following Additional Argument:

- VS2015 Hosted agent: `/p:AndroidNdkDirectory="C:\java\androidsdk\android-ndk-r13b"`
- VS2017 Hosted agent: `/p:AndroidNdkDirectory="$(latestAndroidNDKPath)"`

If you want to know more about this issue I wrote an article that will give you more details:

[Building a Xamarin Android App with Bundle assemblies into native code option enabled on an Azure Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) hosted agent 
(And getting the following error: "Error : Could not find a part of the path 'd:\platforms'."?)](http://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/building-a-xamarin-android-app-with-bundle-assemblies-into-native-code-option-enabled-on-an-azure-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-hosted-agent)

---

How to retrieve the latest Android NDK on a VS2017 hosted agent:

```
$ndk_root = "C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\"

if(Test-Path $ndk_root) {

    $androidNDKs = Get-ChildItem -Path $ndk_root | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

    $latestAndroidNDK = $androidNDKs.FullName;

    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=latestAndroidNDKPath]$latestAndroidNDK" 

} else {

    Write-Host "NDK is not installed at path $ndk_root"

    exit 1
}

Write-Host Variable '$(latestAndroidNDKPath)' is $latestAndroidNDK
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me for an OnPremise Agent

Comment: I was sure this was going to fix it for me but it didn't, Has the path moved on the latest VS2017 Hosted images?

Comment: @JohanFranzén I had to update my answer as things have chance since my first answer in 2017. The path of the NDK depends on the VS2017 install of the Hosted Agent. The best thing to do is to get the latest path in the VS 2017 default Android NDK folder and then set it in a build variable. See my updated answer, I hope this will help

Comment: The two currently installed versions as of this comment on Hosted VS2017 seem to be `C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c` and `android-ndk-r12b`. You can run `dir` in a command prompt task to see what's available.

Answer (score 1):

There is a same issue on Xamarin Forums, and following is the solution in it:

> Fixed: As an update if anyone else having this problem when building
>   Release (that the NDK \toolchains is missing) it appears that mkbundle
>   is broken.
>
> The root cause is that "MakeBundleNativeCodeExternal" is true for
>   release and false for Debug. Although this appears as a licensing
>   issue, my build agent has an Enterprise licence installed.
>
> Disabling "MakeBundleNativeCodeExternal" in Release build by editing
>   the Android project in notepad, seach for 'BundleAssemblies' - and
>   change the 'True' under Release configuration section to ' False'
>   save, build Release, works.

Refer to this link for details: [Missing Android NDK toolchains directory](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7871/missing-android-ndk-toolchains-directory)

Comment: Initially this looked good like it may solve the problem. But Changing this property unfortunately still gave the same error

Comment: @user1 Since there isn't any to configure the Hosted Build Agent and the build can be finished successfully on your local machine. Before figure out the root cause, you can deploy your own build agent to run the build by following the instruction here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows

Comment: I configured my own build agent and installed VisualStudio 2015 Update 2 with Xamarin. This came with the NDK and JDK. I then added the enviroment variables as per [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/tfs-and-xa/](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/tfs-and-xa/) but still getting the same error. I can see the directory now in VisualStudio Agent Pools capabilities and even the toolchains directory but still no luck

Comment: Ok so after getting my solution out of source control on my build agent I found it was missing a Xamarin Component store component. So I got rid of this and it build fine on my local build agent. BUT it still doesnt build on cloud build agents. If I were to guess the problem. I would say that the hosted build agent is probably missing the android NDK enviroment variables

Comment: I changed the following properties from `True` to `False` in my andorid.csproj, `AndroidUseSharedRuntime` and `EmbedAssembliesIntoApk`  and it finally built on a Hosted pool on tfs. But I think this hides the real issue